# Morita equivalence between $\mathbb{C}[G]$ and $\mathbb{C}[H]$?

Tags: group-theory, group-rings

What we can say about two groups G and H when their group rings, $\mathbb{C}[G]$ and $\mathbb{C}[H]$, are Morita equivelent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will assume that $G$ and $H$ are finite groups, since I don't know the theory otherwise. Then it just says that $G$ and $H$ have the same number of conjugacy classes.

Indeed, $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is Morita-equivalent to $\mathbb{C}^m$ where $m$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$, and $\mathbb{C}^m$ is Morita-equivalent to $\mathbb{C}^n$ iff $m=n$.

Comment: The question for infinite groups seems like a quite interesting question. I wonder if an answer is even known.

Comment: Indeed, I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: @CaptainLama tnx for ur answer, it's helpful.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft tnx for being in discussion

Comment: @CaptainLama Do u have any reference in algebraic Morita equivalence?

Comment: I like the Jacobson, Basic Algebra II.